# SetWindowHookEx fails at runtime in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I am building one application use hook, I want start another applicaton , after I build my application and applicaton will get automation window handle of another applicaton and setwindowhook. But I can't do it. Pls help me :( . Sr for my english

variable window is hwnd when I get all applicaton is windowform is running

```
private bool AddWnd(int hwnd, int lparam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
        string className = GetClassName((IntPtr)hwnd).ToString();
        if (className.Length > 10)
        {
            string getSubStringClassName = className.Substring(0, 11);
            if (getSubStringClassName.Equals("WindowsForm") && IsWindow(hwnd)!=0)
            {
                GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
                window = hwnd;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

HookProc HookProcedure;
private const int WH_CBT = 5;

public void startHook()
{
    if (hHook == 0)
    {
        HookProcedure = new HookProc(CbtHookProc);
        int threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)window, out processHandle);
        IntPtr hMod = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(Form1).Module);
        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookProcedure, hMod, threadID);
        if (hHook == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SetWindowsHookEx Failed");
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bool ret = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        //If the UnhookWindowsHookEx function fails.
        if (ret == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UnhookWindowsHookEx Failed");
            return;
        }
        hHook = 0;
        button1.Text = "Set Windows Hook";   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only two types of hooks that you can install from a managed .NET application: the low-level keyboard (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`) and low-level mouse (`WH_MOUSE_LL`) hook. The difference is that the callback function for these two hooks is implemented by your own program. All the other types of hooks require that the callback function be implemented in a DLL that can actually be injected into the hooked process(es). That just doesn't work with managed code because managed DLLs can't be safely injected into unmanaged processes.

So no matter what you do to fix your C# code, this will never work. A computer-based training hook (`WH_CBT`) can never be installed from a C# app or DLL. You will need to switch to a different language to write your hook DLL; C and C++ are common choices.

Or, if all you care about is receiving notifications when another application creates a window, you can use the accessibility APIs instead, which work from managed apps. Start investigating the [`SetWinEventHook` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx). You will need to specify the `WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT` flag in order to ensure that the notifications are delivered to your process; otherwise an injectable DLL is expected, which we already learned won't work. The `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` and/or `EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW` events are the ones you're going to want to monitor.

Comment: There is already a C# version of the accessibility APIs, so you don't need to roll your own: [System.Windows.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.aspx). It is designed for use by WPF applications (i.e., the app doing the controlling is WPF; the app being controlled can be anything).

Comment: please don't use System.Windows.Automation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768047/1204843